# extract values of two specific keys, 'lat' and 'lon', and then place those values in a 2D array (N, 2), entitled coordinates

Tags: arrays, dictionary, for-loop, list-comprehension

Details:
In the code cell below, write and evaluate code to extract the latitude and longitude of every bike station, and store the result in a variable named coordinates. Store the data in a numpy array of shape (N,2), where N is the total number of stations, and 2 reflects the number of columns — store all the longitudes in the first column and all the latitudes in the second column.

Carry out this data extraction however you see fit. The basic steps you will need to carry out are:

import the numpy module
loop over all the station entries in the list of dictionaries returned by datadict['data']['stations']
extract the 'lon' and 'lat' entries associated with each station
build up a list of (lon, lat) pairs, one for each station
convert the list of (lon, lat) pairs to a numpy array with two columns.
After importing numpy, the remaining set of steps above can be done in one line, using a list comprehension to extract the desired pair of fields from each station entry and then converting the list to a numpy array using the np.array function. But if you'd rather break out each step separately within a for loop, that would work too. When you are finished, you should have a numpy array with shape approximately equal to (1000, 2), since there should be approximately 1000 stations in the full array of coordinates (although that number can change over time as new stations are added or removed). Print the shape of the array to determine how many stations are included in the dataset that you downloaded.

This is what I have tried so far, (and does not work):

import numpy as np
coordinates = {key:value for key, value in datadict['data']['stations']}

Not sure what I was expecting, but hopefully get some form of output that I could examine.